# React Native IOS error : Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'yoga.YGNode':

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the following errors related to react-native-image-picker and yoga (whatever that is).
Screenshot of errors in xcode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9fzW.jpg
I'm a ios noob and working with xcode and installing pods is such a pain in the ass, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the same node module - react-native-image-picker. I'll keep an eye on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The image picker node module needs RN 0.69.0 or higher to resolve this issue.

[Include of non-modular header inside framework module](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/2104#issuecomment-1563158532)